# PHP preg_match() on HTML tags

Tags: php, html, preg-match

I am trying to retrieve the  to  using preg_match().

I've written:

```
<?php
$file=file_get_contents('Temp.txt');
$regexp='<div class\=\"cropped-image\" style\=\"width:102px;height:102px;\">(.*)  
</div>';
preg_match($regexp,$file,$string1);
echo $string1[0];
?>
```

Input:

```
<table class="search-results" data-search-total="5068" data-search-type="artists" data-search-term="taylor" data-search-genre="all">
        <tr class="search-result artist">
<td>

    <div class="image">    
        <div class="thumbnail sm artist">
            <a href="/artist/taylor-swift-mn0000472102" data-tooltip="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;MN0000472102&quot;,&quot;thumbnail&quot;:true,&quot;position&quot;:{&quot;my&quot;:&quot;left center&quot;,&quot;at&quot;:&quot;middle right&quot;}}">
                                <div class="cropped-image" style="width:102px;height:102px;" ><img src="http://cps-static.rovicorp.com/3/JPG_170/MI0003/436/MI0003436897.jpg?partner=allrovi.com" style="left:-25px" width="153" height="102" alt="Taylor Swift" data-debug="170x113 (63)"></div>                                </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-of-image">
         <div class="type">
            <span class="sprite2 icon-search-artist-new" title="artist"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="name">
            <a href="http://www.allmusic.com/artist/taylor-swift-mn0000472102" data-tooltip="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;MN0000472102&quot;,&quot;thumbnail&quot;:true,&quot;position&quot;:{&quot;my&quot;:&quot;left center&quot;,&quot;at&quot;:&quot;middle right&quot;}}">Taylor Swift</a>            </div>

        <div class="info">
                                Country, Pop/Rock                            
            <br/>

                                2000s - 2010s                
        </div>

    </div>

</td>
```

The error I'm getting is:Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '(' in TrialPHP.php on line 4. I have included \ before special characters too.

I have tried with [DOM parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and it runs successfully.But I have to use regex for an assignment. How should I proceed??

Comment: That assignment is wrong. You should use DOM for parsing HTML. HTML is not regular text!

Comment: @ParahatMelayev The purpose of the assignment presumably is to learn about regexps, not about parsing DOMs.

Comment: @Barmar then you got something to teach your teacher :)

Comment: @kjetilh It's not _my_ teacher.

Comment: I could *not* know and that's *not* the point :)

Comment: @ParahatMelayev it doesnt matter that its not *regular* text. People are extracting text from HTML every day. It works. The reason why you dont want to use regex for extracting data from HTML is simply that a DOM parser is a specialized tool to do so and thus is more suited because you dont need to teach them the rules.

Comment: @PRamesh you are missing the delimiters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.  Just tested it and it seemed to work:

```
<?php
$file=file_get_contents('test.txt');

$regexp='/\<div class\=\"cropped-image\" style\=\"width:102px;height:102px;\" \>(.*?)\<\/div\>/';
preg_match($regexp,$file,$string1);

//print_r($string1);
//echo "<hr />\n\n";
echo $string1[1];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. But can you tell me why the String[0] was throwing an error?? Dont array indices start from 0??

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that I got Notice: Undefined offset: 0 Error while using string1[0]

Comment: I'm not too sure.  Maybe it wasn't returning anything to `$string1`.  Yes arrays are 0 based, but remember, with preg_match $string1[0] will return the full matched pattern (so it will include the <div> and everything) and [1] will return the first matched sub-pattern (.*).  If you uncomment that line in my code with the print_r, run it, and view the source, you can see the contents of the array.

Comment: When I try the code in the answer, `$string1[0]` works fine.

Comment: Yes but view the source.  It will include the <div>. [0] is the full match

Answer (score 1):

You need a delimiter, for example `#`.

Try:

```
$regexp='#<div class="cropped-image" style="width:102px;height:102px;" >(.*)</div>#';
```

Comment: Yes, tried that. I got Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in TrialPHP.php on line 5 Error.

Comment: Removed the [] from output and I get Notice: Array to string conversion Error.

Comment: because it doesn't match anything and `$string1 = array()`. I updated my answer. It works on my computer now.